# Weird /'http URL pattern leading to many 404s

Tags: google, google-search-console, wordpress, url

I got very weird 404s from the Google Search Console.  It shows me some kind of URL mix up and I cannot pinpoint where this pattern comes from. It is a WordPress installation.

`https://example.com/blog/page/12/’https://go.example.com/20190620-Lyft-Livestream.html?ref=blog`

`https://example.com/blog/page/13/’https://go.example.com/Retail_Webinar_Registration.html?ref=blog`

`https://example.com/blog/page/14/’https://go.example.com/WBR190710AI_Registration.html?ref=blog`

Do you know how these may have been generated?

Comment: Do you recognize the `/WBR190710AI_Registration.html?ref=blog` link?  Is that something you have on your site or a WordPress plugin might be putting on your site?

Comment: Thanks for jumping in. This is the lead gen pages module. I guess that a plugin / app is used to manage these. It looks like the go.example.com is still using WordPress to host the lead gen pages. What is your idea?

Comment: Can you view the page source on one of your pages, find the HTML code around this link, and paste that into your question?  I'll bet the code is broken in some subtle way.

Comment: I have checked a couple of pages and the link cannot be found in the HTML. I guess it is autogenerated somehow but it is not hardcoded in the code.

Comment: What is the URL of your website?  Maybe we can check for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This certainly looks like a mistyped URL in the links on pages `/blog/page/12/`, `/blog/page/13/` and `/blog/page/14/`. On those pages look for a link like the following:

```
<a href='’https://go.example.com/20190620-Lyft-Livestream.html?ref=blog'>Link</a>
```

The erroneous single back curly quote `’` at the start of the URL will trigger the user-agent (browser / Googlebot) to treat the URL as *relative*.

Since this is affecting numerous different URLs then maybe this is a typo in a template?

Comment: Actual URLs of pages could even be `/blog/page/12/url-slug-text` which would still give the same result for relative URLs.

Comment: Would double single quotes actually produce the issue?  It might depend on the parser, but I'd think that would be an empty `href` followed by an attribute starting with `https://...`.   `<a href="'http...">` would be much more likely to exhibit the problem I would think.

Comment: Yes, double single quotes would result in an empty `href`, followed by something... I used a single + curly quote since it was a curly quote in the question (maybe a problem with the editor being used?). But yes, a double+single quote would also exhibit a similar problem (with a single quote at the start).

Comment: I would consider the question answered and ask my front end colleagues to check the templates. Thank you!